# how many resources nmon command use in AIX?

Tags: linux, ssh, aix, resource-monitor, resource-usage

I need to store in an external repository, every minute (in near realtime mode), the nmon information saved in a temporary file.

So what would be the best scenario:

1) every minute I open an ssh shell, run the below command and export it in the external repository

```
nmon -F filename -c 1 -s 15
```

where

```
parameter c -> Specifies the number snapshots that must be taken by the command
parameter s -> Specifies the interval in seconds between 2 consecutive recording snapshots
```

2) every 10 minutes I open an ssh shell, run the below command and export it in the external repository

```
nmon -F filename -c 10 -s 60
```

What do you suggest in order to reduce resources consumption?

Thanks in advange